# Using strcpy throws "stack smashing detected" error

Tags: c++, c

I have two types of `struct`s, `struct msg` and `struct pkt`.
My job is to construct a `struct pkt` using `struct msg` passed as an argument.

```
struct msg {
  char data[20];
  };

struct pkt {
   int seqnum;
   int acknum;
   int checksum;
   char payload[20];
    };
```

While

```
void A_output(struct msg message) { //fails
    ...
    struct pkt snd_pkt;
    strcpy(snd_pkt.payload, message.data);
    ...
}
```

fails,

```
void A_output(struct msg message) { //succeeds
    ...
    struct pkt snd_pkt;
    memcpy(&snd_pkt.payload, &message, sizeof(struct msg));
    ...
}
```

succeeds.

What I do not understand is, if I am copying char[20] to char[20], and used `strcpy`, shouldn't it be fine? Why is it throwing stack smashing error?

Why, in the working answer, is it copying memory of type `struct msg` to the memory of `char[20]` field in `struct pkt`, and why should the third argument be `sizeof(struct msg)`, not strlen(message.data) + 1?

Comment: `strcpy` requires null-terminated strings. Maybe you aren't passing it what it expects.

Comment: It's ran by a simulator, and the string passed from the function call was of length 20 (+1 for null). I don't know why they defined the string as char array of size 20(I'm not allowed to change) if they are going to pass size 21 char array.

Comment: Yeah... you can't hold 21 elements in an array of 20.

Comment: So, yo uneed to use `memcpy` and not treat the array like a string. Either that or it is a buggy design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I do not understand is, if I am copying char[20] to char[20], and
>   used strcpy, shouldn't it be fine?

It will be fine if data member data of structure msg is zero terminated that is if it contains a string. It seems that ther reason of the error is that it does not contain a string.
As for this statement

```
memcpy(&snd_pkt.payload, &message, sizeof(struct msg));
```

then in general case it has undefined behaviour because due to the structure alignment the sizeof the structure can be greater than 20 bytes for example when sizeof( int is equal to 8.

Answer (score 4):

```
strcpy(snd_pkt.payload, message.data);
```

shoud be fine only if your char array data is null terminated.
Alternately, you may use:

```
size_t ss = sizeof(snd_pkt.payload);   
strncpy(snd_pkt.payload, message.data, ss-1);
snd_pkt.payload[ss-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Indeed... but don't forget http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: `strncpy` actually seems appropriate here (although I'd still prefer `snprintf`)

Comment: Suggest `sizeof snd_pkt.payload - 1` rather than `20-1` `19`, etc.

Comment: -1 for adding `\0` after `strncpy`. If `.data` is supposed to be zero terminated, but isn't, then you have a bug in your program, and the correct course of action is to call `abort()`. Trying to "fix" invalid data doesn't solve any problems. It just creates harder to catch bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple for loop also does the job pretty well:

```
void A_output(struct msg message) {
...
struct pkt snd_pkt;
int i=0,
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
   snd_pkt.payload[i] = msg.data[i];
}
...
```